# Display search box from custom plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have developed one custom plugin in a nopCommerce. In which I want to display search box from my plugin, how it can be possible? There is no any route defined for SearchBox action method. It is directly invoked from Header.cshtml page by below code:

```
@Html.Action("SearchBox", "Catalog")
```

I have tried with plugin view engine, but it doesn't work. I want to display SearchBox from my plugin. Moreover, I do not want to use Action Filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are use plugin view engine then it's possible for you.

So in your plugin you can use below code for view page override in nopcommerce.

```
"~/Plugins/your.plugin.name/Views/Catalog/{0}.cshtml"
```

Hope this is help for you